# Why might the address of "this" in C++ change?

Tags: c++, this, memory-address

I have a situation in which I have an object of type Foo, in which calling its own methods somehow loses track of its own address in "this".  I have defined these functions:

```
// Bar has an instance of foo, and wishes to call a function001()...
Bar::doThingWithFoo(){

    // foo is at address 0x1a7bbb70 here...
    foo->function001();

}

// The definition of function001().  The address of "this" is as expected.
Foo::function001(){

    // the address of "this" is 0x1a7bbb70 here...
    this->function002();  

}

Foo::function002(){

    // but the address of "this" is 0xbfffe090 here!!!
    // bad things happen, as you might expect.
    this->getMyProperty()->doThing();

}
```

Why might something like this happen?

Comment: Could you please include `Foo`'s class definition?

Comment: Maybe memory/stack corruption?

Comment: This is crying out for an SSCCE.

Comment: May be you are calling the methods from different instances?

Comment: By "address of this", you do mean value of `this`, right? The value is the location of the object.

Comment: Actual code please.  This pseudocode is utterly useless in diagnosing your problem.

Comment: you are correct, chris.  I mean the address that the keyword "this" represents.  Everything appears to be correct right up until that function002 call at which point the address of "this" is mysteriously different.

Comment: @scriptocalypse : I suspect you've unintentionally copied your `Foo` object somewhere, and ultimately have a different instance that `function002` is called on. Or, you're just calling `function002` on an uninitialized `Foo*`.

Comment: a SSCCE might be a tall order.  I'll work on it however.

Comment: @scriptocalypse you should.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are using multiple inheritance, which causes the pointer value of `this` to be context-dependent:

http://frogchunk.com/documentation/lang/cpp/Multiple_inheritance_and_the_this_pointer.pdf

That causes problems if you use C casts instead of `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: The gap in addresses makes me think it unlikely this is the issue.

Comment: I am no longer in front of the machine, but this might be closer to the truth than you'd guess.  It's not Foo that's using multiple inheritance but one of its member variables that acts as a delegate.  The last thing I noticed before leaving the office was that this behvaior happens immediately after that delegate is called, and indeed, that delegate is assigned using a C-style cast instead of a dynamic_cast.  Point being, it could be that the delegate object somehow is being accessed incorrectly, and thus causing great havoc when it is called upon.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that we need to see the actual code.  I will speculate that `0xbfffe090` looks like an address on the stack which means you may have accidentally copied your object and then invoked a method on the copy.  It would also be consistent with some kind of memory corruption (overwriting a local array, for example) with some local address.

Comment: As I think about it, there must be some sort of memory corruption going on, and I think the issue isn't Foo itself.  It doesn't appear to be a local copy.  I am no longer in front of the machine, but all these thoughts have given me some good ideas to look for.

Answer (score 1):

Wild speculative guess would be what others have also eluded to that you might be having some sort of buffer over-flow case at other place in your code where the buffer overflow is corrupting this.

It would help to know the code.

I would imagine if its a memory corruption it would cause it have a core dump, did you notice one ?

Comment: This isn't really an answer - it would be better off in comments on the question

Comment: @alexwhan : That can be said of every answer so far. It's kind of unavoidable when the question is so lacking in necessary details...

Comment: I think the distinction is when you look at the other answers, they give a specific (though speculative) answer. It seems a good rule of thumb is if you ask a question in your answer, it's not really an answer... not trying to be harsh here, just trying to explain how SO seems to work - all the best.

Comment: @alexwhan : I am very new to the forum (as a contributor, but have been benefitting by reading different discussions). I'll be careful.

Comment: No problem, wevre all just trying to help each other. Hope you get lots out of SO

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question : alltom's answer was actually closer than it might seem, but ultimately it was of course memory corruption.  Memory became corrupted inside function001 prior to function002 being called because of an object being used as a delegate.  The delegate had been passed and stored as a void*, and C-style cast back into its object type to call its relevant methods.

The issue was resolved by storing the delegate object in a variable (eg: MyDelegate* delegate) rather than storing as void* and casting.